# Using g.render in a grails service

Tags: ajax, json, grails, render

I'm trying to use g.render in a grails service, but it appears that g is not provided to services by default.  Is there a way to get the templating engine to render a view in the service?  I may be going about this the wrong way.  What I'm looking to to is render the view from a partial template to a string, and send the resulting string back as part of a JSON response to be used with AJAX updates.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For any searchers who wander across this page lo these many years later, don't forget that rendering a template from a service means that the template won't have the same context it would have if rendered from a controller; so, if you are using, e.g., `createLink` in the GSP, you'll need to specify the `controller` as well as the `action`!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I totally agree with John's argumentation - doing GSP in services is generally a bad design decision. But no rules without exceptions! If you still want to do this, try the following approach:

```
class MyService implements InitializingBean {
    boolean transactional = false
    def gspTagLibraryLookup  // being automatically injected by spring
    def g

    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        g = gspTagLibraryLookup.lookupNamespaceDispatcher("g")
        assert g
    }

    def serviceMethod() {    
       // do anything with e.g. g.render
    }
}
```

Using the gspTagLibraryLookup bean you can of course access every other desired taglib in a service.

Comment: with great power comes great responsibility! becareful when doing things like this - make sure you know the reasoning behind rendering gsp in a service before doing it :)

Comment: My intent was to render a template and then return with with JSON so the resulting HTML could be inserted.  I was going to encapsulate the logic in a service, but found that just returning the JSON manually in each controller works just as well, and g.render is already available.  Thanks everyone for your input.

Comment: It also has another problem... It's harder to create unit tests for the services if they depend on the controller.

Comment: I needed that to return some HTML from a single entry service (kind of command pattern). This was very handful. Many thanks

Answer (score 16):

It's even simpler now in Grails 2 with the PageRenderer.  e.g.:

```
class SomeService {
    def groovyPageRenderer

    void someMethod() {
        String html = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: '/email/someTemplateName')
    }
}
```

API - http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/gsp/PageRenderer.html

More complete example - http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html

Comment: almost missed your answer, thanks for adding it. looks smooth now with new Grails

Comment: Easy and simple. But [Stefan's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service/1778991#1778991) answer offer solution for any tag. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 4):

My advice would be to do this in the controller.  Service should have reusable logic and not depend on a view template, leave that work to the controller.  Use the service to get the data you need to pass to the template, but leave the work of interacting with the template to the controller.

Comment: Sorry, but even if your answer is a good advice, it is not an acceptable answer: there are ways to achieve what was asked, even if not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that's similar to [Stefan's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service/1778991#1778991), but a bit simpler

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware

class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationTagLib g

    void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        g = applicationContext.getBean(ApplicationTagLib)

        // now you have a reference to g that you can call render() on
    }
}
```