# How to access the g.-namespace in a Domain Class

Tags: grails, internationalization

I would like to make use of the g.message() functionality in the toString method of my domain class, but the g.-namespace is not accessible by default. 
I doubt that a `import g.*` will do the trick.

I already know that I can use the `messageSource` functionality, but it would be nicer to use the same syntax as in the views.

Comment: it wasn't easy to decide which answer to accept. Both are good. SO I decided on the number of votes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
class MyDomain {

  def someMethod() {
    def g = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean( 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib' )
    return g.message(....)
  }

}
```

or else you can get `messageSource` directly: `ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean('messageSource')`

Comment: Be aware though that `ApplicationHolder` is deprecated in grails 2.0, and ([according to the javadoc](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationHolder.html)), you should *"Use dependency injection or implement GrailsApplicationAware instead"*

Comment: nice solution, but not too groovy. Isn't there a shorter name for the `ApplicationTagLib`? The messageSource can easily be injected through a `def messageSource` but the API needs (afaik) the locale.

Comment: ok, you can use `import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib` + `.getBean(ApplicationTagLib)`, if it looks more groovier :)

Comment: This is indeed groovier! Now I only have to find a way how to get rid of the `ApplicationHolder`...

Answer (score 2):

[Using g.render in a grails service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service/1778991) has some hints how to use "g:" in a service. I have not tested this, but it should work mostly the same in domain classes, with one important exception: a domain class cannot use InitializingBean since it's not a bean residing in the application context.

Comment: Just tested this. It works but I hoped to find a simpler solution... A solution where maybe the ApplicationTagLib is injected as service... How do I know what kind of services are available for injection? Is there somewhere a list?

Comment: the appinfo plugin gives you an overview on what can be injected.