# g.formatDate raises error when executed from a Job?

Tags: grails, groovy

I use a Grails Job to start a Service which uses `g.formatDate`. When using the service directly from a Controller I have no problem. When I use the Service from the Job I get the following error:

```
ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: Grails Job
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
   Line | Method
->> 111 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   202 | run     in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run . . in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 245 | $tt__sendReportCompanyWeekly in Test.SendMailService$$EPPc274K
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    47 | doCall  in Test.ReportCompanyWeeklyJob$_execute_closure1
|    31 | execute in Test.ReportCompanyWeeklyJob$$EPPc2HTU
|   104 | execute in grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsJob
|   202 | run . . in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run     in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
```

Here is my Job:

```
class ReportCompanyWeeklyJob {  

  SendMailService sendMailService


  static triggers = {
    cron name: 'scheduledReportCompanyWeeklyJob', cronExpression: "0 15 22 ? * *" 
  }

  def execute() {
    sendMailService.sendReportCompanyWeekly(company.id, user.id)
  }

}
```

Here is my Service:

```
@Transactional
class SendMailService {

    def gspTagLibraryLookup  // being automatically injected by spring
    def g

  def sendReportCompanyWeekly(String companyId, String userId) {    
    g = gspTagLibraryLookup.lookupNamespaceDispatcher("g")

    Date today = new Date()
    Locale locale = // some locale

    // Line 245
    def test = g.formatDate(date: today, formatName: 'date.format.long.no.year', locale: locale)  

 }

}
```

Edit: I use `groovyPageRenderer.render(template: viewPathHTML, model: myModel)` to render a GSP in a service.

**How can I make `g.formatDate` work when running from a Job?**

Comment: Why are you calling gsp tags from a service?

Comment: Because I have to render a GSP template for an email.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24487712/6509 ?

Comment: No totally wrong answer.

Comment: I use ``groovyPageRenderer.render(template: viewPathHTML, model: myModel)`` to render a GSP in a service. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: you can try instantiating `ApplicationTagLib` in your service

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908231/how-to-access-the-g-namespace-in-a-domain-class or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777640/using-g-render-in-a-grails-service/1778991

Comment: @injecteer I tried both of your links none of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grails.gsp.PageRenderer` is limited in what it can render because it doesn't have the same context as rendering GSP pages from a controller.

When using a *formatName*, `g.formatDate()` attempts to get a *Locale* from the the `GrailsWebRequest`. The *Locale* is used to retrieve 'date.format.long.no.year' from a [MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html). The problem is `grails.gsp.PageRenderer` does not have a `GrailsWebRequest`. You can see the `g.formatDate()` source code [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/23461301a310956df6c8f7c49f12d189b906f55e/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormatTagLib.groovy).

## Work-around

You can work around this problem by formatting the date in the service and passing it to the GSP via the model. Something like this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

@Transactional
class SendMailService {

    ...
    def messageSource // Injected to look up 'date.format.long.no.year'

    def sendReportCompanyWeekly(String companyId, String userId) {    
        Date today = new Date()
        Locale locale = // some locale

        def formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(messageSource.getMessage('date.format.long.no.year', null, locale), locale)
            .format(today)

        /* 
          1. Add the formattedDate to the PageRenderer model, 
          2. Update the GSP code to use the value from the model instead of g.formatDate()
        */
    }

}
```

## Better idea - create a formatDate Closure

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

@Transactional
class SendMailService {

    ...
    def messageSource // Injected to look up 'date.format.long.no.year'

    def sendReportCompanyWeekly(String companyId, String userId) {    
        Date today = new Date()
        Locale locale = // some locale

        def formatter= new SimpleDateFormat(messageSource.getMessage('date.format.long.no.year', null, locale), locale)

        def formatDate = { Date date -> formatter.format(date) }

        /* 
          1. Add the formatDate Closure to the PageRenderer model, 
          2. Update the GSP code to use the Closure from the model instead of g.formatDate()
        */
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I call the closure? Wouldn't it be better to create a tagLib for that?

Comment: Here's an example `<div>${myFormatDate(somedate)}<\div>` If you create a taglib you'll have to pass in enough parameters (such as the Locale) so it can use a  MessageSource. Possible but trickier.

Comment: Do you have an example for a taglib too?