# Grails send data from service to view

Tags: grails

In Grails, can a Service send data to a view directly? Or must it be through the controller? And if it can, I kindly request to be pointed to a tutorial or example if anyone is aware of one. Thanks.

Comment: interfacing with a view should really be left to a controller in my opinion. Services are more for reusable code that is view-agnostic, and accessed by a controller. Maybe you could make your question more specific to your use-case to see what other approaches might be valid? Depending on what you want to achieve, this thread might also be of help(?) http://stackoverflow.com/q/1777640/3651800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Service can't really send data to a view.  Requests are typically handled by a controller and the controller can do things like return a model or render a view and specify a model.  The model data could be retrieved from a service but the controller is still responsible for delivering the data to the view.  If you have an understanding of the request cycle it will become clear why a service can't send data to a view.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think that's just the problem, me not understanding the request cycle. I've been trying to use the Grails g:formUpload to work with my jQuery UI progress bar all day and since my Service is actually handling the file upload, I am at a complete loss as to where to get the data to feed my jQuery UI progressbar. If you can point me to any sources I'd be much obliged. I've been at this since 7:00a.m. and now it is 9:20pm. I've never struggled so hard without any progress in one single day. Amazing. Paying my dues for being a newbie...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but the short answer is "*No, a service can not send data directly to a view*." At least, typically.

To understand why I say "*typically*" you need to understand how a typical HTTP request cycle is handled. Let's start there.

A `Client` (browser) makes a request to a `Controller`. The `controller` can interact with `services` and `domain classes` to build a `model` (data) which is then given to a `view` and rendered as a `response` to the request made by the browser.

`Browser` -> `Controller` -> `Services & Domains` -> `Controller Model` -> `View` -> `Response`

That's the typical route.

However, using something like a long poll technique or websockets does change this slightly. These do enable you to put messages onto a bus which is streamed to the client and these messages can be generated by a service. It's a fairly large and complex topic into itself.

Now, until you have mastered or fully understand the typical HTTP conversation, diving into the more complex one isn't going to be possible. Start simple, master that, then move onto the complex.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. I hugely appreciate. I am trying to upload files in my Grails application. I got that part figured out very quickly using the g:uploadForm. The trouble started when I wanted to hook up a progress bar to the process. So, I tried it with jQuery UI progressbar and that is what I was trying to accomplish all day. I made three different posts (I think) today as I had questions along the process if you care to visit them just to see my code samples and thought process, or lack there of perhaps :) cnt type lngr cmmnt. bt bscly can't fig out how to seed progbar.

Comment: I've never used it, but have you looked at: http://grails.org/plugin/super-file-upload